# get input values in a sorted fashion

Tags: jquery

I have dynamically generated input boxes with ids in the following format:

```
<input id="box_1" />
<input id="box_2" />
```

What's the best way for me to get the values sorted by the corresponding id nums in jquery?

Answer (score 1):

**Html :**

```
<input id="box_1" value=""/>
<input id="box_2" value=""/>
<input type="button" value="submit" id="btn"/>
```

**JS :**

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $('input[id^="box_"]').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr("id")+" : "+$(this).val());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8cxm0ha1/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use:

```
<input id="box_1" name="box[]" />
<input id="box_2" name="box[]" />
```

This will come as an array in the `POST`, and in jQuery, you can use:

```
$('input[name="box[]"]').val().join(", ");
```

Comment: @Riz That would be based on the location of the `<input />` tags.

Comment: yes it seems it's in the order the elements are rendered on the page: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type

Comment: @Riz Wow, that's interesting. Shall I provide you with a different solution?

Comment: You may probably wish to use the `data-` attributes associated with the HTML5. So that, based on those attributes and having a common class name, you can sort and organize the data. `:)`

Comment: are you sure this works? I get $(...).val(...).join is not a function error

Comment: @Riz give me a few mins so that I'll send you a working fiddle. I'm on travel now. Yes, it works for me.